# different results of same res.render

Tags: node.js

So I am having an issue with the rendering of a view after the info is updated on mongoose. here is the code:

```
router.post('/delete',(req,res) => {
    const {idItem} = req.body
    console.log(idItem)
    MenuItem.findOneAndUpdate({_id:idItem},{is_active:0}).then(item =>{
        req.flash(
            'success_msg',
            'The item has been disabled'
        )
        let items = []
        MenuItem.find({is_active:1}).then(item => {
            items = item
            res.render('menu', {pageTitle:'Menu', navBarOn:'1', userLevel:req.user.userLevel, userName:req.user.fname, userLname:req.user.lname, items})
        }).catch(rej => console.log(rej))
    })
})
```

The information us updated on mongoDB and the promise gets resolved but when is time to render it just doesn't work. I have used this method previously with the save instead of the findOneAndUpdate:

```
newItem.save().then(menuItem =>{
                    req.flash(
                        'success_msg',
                        'The item has been added to the menu'
                    )
                    let items = []
                    MenuItem.find({is_active:1}).then(item => {
                        items = item
                        res.render('menu', {pageTitle:'Menu', navBarOn:'1', userLevel:req.user.userLevel, userName:req.user.fname, userLname:req.user.lname, items})
                    })
                })
```

and it works just fine but in here the page is nor rendered a new.

Any thoughts?

Comment: if you have `.then()`, remember that you also need `.catch()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have added `/menu` in the `res.render()` function as the view. Removing that should work as the `render()` function takes a view name.

Check this link: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render

Comment: I changed the url to be ```menu``` but the error persists